# Granting unique permissions to a page

Tags: permissions, sharepoint-permissions, unique-permissions

I have a SharePoint site which is made up of a page (Home), 4 lists and 1 document library.

For the whole site, we have the site owners, site members and site visitors groups and my understanding is people in these can access the whole site – all lists, home page and document library.

However, for the lists and document library we have stopped inheriting parent permissions and added people individually so there are people that only have access to 1 list, or document library, or 2 lists etc, and not the whole site.

My problem is that regardless of whether someone has access to the whole site, or just 1 list, or 1 library etc, I need them to have access to the Home page, or a page that has important information on it about the information on the site and what they can/can't do with it. I thought everyone would still be able to see the Home page, but I tested with a colleague the other day and noticed this wasn’t the case, she could only access the 1 list she had been granted access to. However, when I click on the home page I can’t see any way to grant access specifically to this page. I tried creating a new page, but this also didn’t work as it seems this is linked with granting access to the whole site. What are my options here please?

Comment: Are you using SharePoint Online or any other version of SharePoint?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to set permissions on a single page within a site then follow below steps;

1. Go to the Site Pages library.
2. Then set the permissions on a page level the same way you would set permissions on a document, folder or site.

Check below article for detailed steps:

[SharePoint Groups and Page Level Permission in SharePoint 2013](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/746cd9/sharepoint-groups-and-page-level-permission-in-sharepoint-20/).