# Set Specific User Restrictions on certain pages

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, modern-experience, navigation, sitepages

I have a SharePoint Site and I want to start uploading Employee Contracts & Personal Data to their own "Profile Page" - however I don't want every member of staff to be able to access other Staff contracts for obvious reasons.

How can I set up a page that only myself (as a manager) and the employee can access but is unique to just those 2 users? I would need about 10 pages as I have 10 members of staff all of which they would need to be able to access their own "Profile" but I would need to be able to have access too.

Also, is it possible to have a custom navigation? So for example, as an employee on their top level navigation bar it might say "My Profile" but for me as a manager my navigation bar might be a drop down with the top level saying "Employee Profiles"?

Sorry for the long winded question...I'm fairly new to SPO.

Answer (score 0):

You can break permission inheritance on each SharePoint site page and grant necessary access to employee and manager as per your requirements.

Follow below steps to set permissions on a single page within a site:

1. Go to the Site Pages library.
2. Select site page, click on ellipses (...) and select Manage access:

   [image]
3. Select Advanced link from manage access popup, it will open classic permissions page in new tab.

   [image]
4. Select Stop inheriting permissions > OK:

   [image]
5. Grant necessary permissions using "Grant Permissions" option > Add employee, manager permissions and grant Full control permissions to site admins to avoid any issues in future:

   [image]
6. If any additional permissions are granted initially/by default and you want to remove those, you can select user/group and remove permissions using "Remove User Permissions" option. Make sure you are not removing site admin permissions, it is best practice to have Full control permissions to site admins on all pages:

   [image]

**Similar thread**: [Granting unique permissions to a page](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/275322/granting-unique-permissions-to-a-page)

Comment: Hi , have you tried the method provided by Ganesh Sanap? Is it helpful?

Comment: Hi @AmyJiang_MSFT, thanks for your comment, really appreciate it. I think we have to add comment on user's original question as users will not see the your comment notification unless they have previously commented on this answer thread.

Comment: Ok, thank you for reminding me. :)

Comment: Thanks to you for commenting. I faced similar issues, user not getting notified for comments added by me. So, just wanted to inform you!