# Access denied for members

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, microsoft-teams, sharepoint-permissions, office-365-groups

**User A** is member of a Teams based SharePoint. Therefor he should have access to all files on the SharePoint. Permissions to files folder also contain the members group with editing rights. But User A can't navigate to some random folders, he only get's an "access denied" screen.

**User B** is owner of the SharePoint and therefor in the owner group. He can see and use all files.

When using the "Check permission" option in the site permissions for **User A** he has multiple times limited access although there is no (visible) limitation.

Any suggestions what's wrong?

Comment: Are you using item level permissions for those specific folders/files, check it once.

Comment: There are only sharing link, no modification of direct access.

Unfortunately the users informed other members of new files by creating multiple sharing links for the other members instead of just copying the link. So some files have multiple sharing links for user which already have access due to their member status.

Comment: When you create a sharing link, it creates item level permissions. Follow the steps given here and confirm if folder/files are using unique permissions. Let me know if you need any help while following the steps: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/307438/set-specific-user-restrictions-on-certain-pages/307441#307441

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the answer was unexpected simple:

There is a **SharePoint group** "Members of ..." which contained some individual users and grants access to the files.

The **O365 group**  "Members of ..." was not part of it. Seems like someone removed it. After I re-added the *O365 group* to the *SharePoint group* all members had normal access.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using item level (unique) permissions for those specific folders/files where user get's an "access denied" screen.

Follow below steps to confirm if folders/files are using item level (unique) permissions and delete unique permissions to inherit default permissions from document library/SharePoint site:

1. Go to your document library.
2. Select the file/folder, click on ellipses (...) and then select **Manage access**
3. Select **Advanced** link at the bottom of manage access popup, it will open classic permissions page in new tab.
4. From **PERMISSIONS** tab, check if you are using unique permissions for selected file/folder (it will look something like below given image)

   [image]
5. Click **Delete unique permissions** to inherit default permissions from document library/SharePoint site again.

**Similar thread**: [Set Specific User Restrictions on certain pages](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/307438/set-specific-user-restrictions-on-certain-pages/307441#307441)

Comment: I checked that and the whole tree from the file to the root of the library has no unique permission but instead inherits from the library itself. Members have access to the library but can't see folders or files. I found out that there are 250.000 items in the library. Does that affect permissions?