# Different permission for list items and comments

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, permissions, modern-experience, item-level-permissions

I have created a list in SharePoint and would like to have a group of users that can add items to the list, and then have all users in the organization add comments to the items. Is it possible to set the permissions so that this is possible?

Comment: As Ganesh Sanap said, you need at least edit permission.

Answer (score 0):

As per this article [SharePoint Online: All you need to know about Commenting in Lists](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/01/09/all-you-need-to-know-about-commenting-in-lists/),

You need at least **Edit** permissions on list items to add new comments on the SharePoint list items.

So, you can try this:

1. Grant **Read** permissions to all users in the organization on SharePoint list (or site - as per your requirements)
2. Break permissions inheritance on individual list items and grant **Edit** permissions to all users in the organization

Follow the steps given here for more information for breaking permissions inheritance: [Set Specific User Restrictions on certain pages](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/307438/set-specific-user-restrictions-on-certain-pages/307441#307441)